# If G-d does not lack anything what is meant when it says that he desires prayers of the righteous?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology

I believe that rashi says that the reason God made the avos/imos barren is so that they would pray since God desires the prayers of the righteous.

There's also the idea in Judaism that God is a perfect being that doesn't lack anything (a common theme in books on Jewish ethics). From my understanding a being that doesn't lack does not desire anything - you only desire something that you lack.

If so what does it mean that God desires the prayers of the righteous?

Comment: Why do you assume desire=lack? Does a parent's desire that a child say "please" show a personal "lack" on their part?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Shimshon Pinkus Zatzal in his Sefarim writes that the purpose and reason of Tefila is not that Hashem is lacking anything, it is solely for our benefit in order for us to have a connection with Hashem.

Comment: so what does it mean that God desires the prayers of the righteous?